# Iterate Python data structure

Tags: python

I'm having problems getting my head around this Python data structure:

```
 data = {'nmap': {'command_line': u'ls',
                  'scaninfo': {u'tcp': {'method': u'connect',
                                        'services': u'80,443'}},
                  'scanstats': {'downhosts': u'0',
                                'elapsed': u'1.18',
                                'timestr': u'Wed Mar 19 21:37:54 2014',
                                'totalhosts': u'1',
                                'uphosts': u'1'}},
         'scan': {u'url': {'addresses': {u'ipv6': u'2001:470:0:63::2'},
                                        'hostname': u'abc.net',
                                        'status': {'reason': u'syn-ack',
                                                   'state': u'up'},
                                        u'tcp': {80: {'conf': u'3',
                                                      'cpe': '',
                                                      'extrainfo': '',
                                                      'name': u'http',
                                                      'product': '',
                                                      'reason': u'syn-ack',
                                                      'state': u'open',
                                                      'version': ''},
                                                 443: {'conf': u'3',
                                                       'cpe': '',
                                                       'extrainfo': '',
                                                       'name': u'https',
                                                       'product': '',
                                                       'reason': u'syn-ack',
                                                       'script': {
                                                           u'ssl-cert': u'place holder'},
                                                       'state': u'open',
                                                       'version': ''}},
                                        'vendor': {}
         }
         }
 }
```

Basically I need to iterate over the 'tcp' key values and extract the contents of the 'script' item if it exists.

This is what I've tried:

```
items = data["scan"]
for item in items['url']['tcp']:
    if t["script"] is not None:
        print t
```

However I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: You mixed up `item` and `t` btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find any dictionary items with the key `'script'` anywhere in the data structure:

```
def find_key(data, search_key, out=None):
    """Find all values from a nested dictionary for a given key."""
    if out is None:
        out = []
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        if search_key in data:
            out.append(data[search_key])
        for key in data:
            find_key(data[key], search_key, out)
    return out
```

For your data, I get:

```
>>> find_key(data, 'script')
[{'ssl-cert': 'place holder'}]
```

---

To find the ports, too, modify slightly:

```
tcp_dicts = find_key(data, 'tcp') # find all values for key 'tcp'
ports = [] # list to hold ports
for d in tcp_dicts: # iterate through values for key 'tcp'
    if all(isinstance(port, int) for port in d): # ensure all are port numbers
        for port in d:
            ports.append((port, 
                          d[port].get('script'))) # extract number and script
```

Now you get something like:

```
[(80, None), (443, {'ssl-cert': 'place holder'})]
```

Comment: One more question here. If I wanted to include the 'tcp' ports i.e. 80 and 443 in the out data, how could I do that?

Comment: Not sure if I'm with you here! I assume I keep the original function as it? I can't seem to get this to work! Basically the bits I need in my output data are: "ipv6" address, "hostname", "tcp" port numbers, "status" and the contents of "script"

Comment: Ah, I see there are places where the key `'tcp'` *doesn't* give a dictionary of port numbers. I have updated to deal with this. And yes, this is using the existing implementation of `find_key`. All those things that weren't in your question you can still use `find_key` for.

Answer (score 1):

`data['scan']['url']['tcp']` is a dictionary, so when you just iterate over it, you will get the *keys* but not the values. If you want to iterate over the values, you have to do so:

```
for t in data['scan']['url']['tcp'].values():
    if 'script' in t and t['script'] is not None:
        print(t)
```

If you need the key as well, iterate over the items instead:

```
for k, t in data['scan']['url']['tcp'].items():
    if 'script' in t and t['script'] is not None:
        print(k, t)
```

You also need to change your test to check `'script' in t` first, otherwise accessing `t['script']` will raise a key error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean `if item["script"]`?

Really though if the key has a chance to not exist, use the `get` method provided by `dict`.

So try instead

```
items = data["scan"]
for item in items['url']['tcp']:
    script = item.get('script')
    if script:
        print script
```